# Outlook Web App - edit HTML for accesibility

Tags: outlook-web-app

In my office we must use the Outlook Web App, instead MS Outlook. I would like to edit the HTML message to include some accesibility help for the clients, because they are blind and they work with JAWS.

For example, I would like to introduce a `<span lang>` when I use words in other language, or `<abbr>`, or at least, alternative text for images.

Is there any way to achieve this, maybe with plugins or something?

If it helps, my OWA version is Premium 14.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same frustration.  I wanted to edit my own html code and could not find a way to di it in Outlook Web.  I decided to open a blank Notepad document and put my html code there.  Then I change the file extension on the document from '.txt' to '.htm'.  I opened the document up, selected everything, and pasted my results into my Outlook Web email.  To my surprise, it worked!

Note: You need to have file extensions showing in order to be able to change a file extension. Go to Control Panel > Folder Options > View, then uncheck the box in front of: "Hide extensions for known file types"